# Can I tell CoffeeScript to retain newlines in it's vanilla javascript output

Tags: coffeescript

**CoffeeScript Input:**

```
noob = [
  'learning'
  'new'
  'language'
]
```

or

```
vector.x >=0 && 
vector.x < this.width &&
vector.y >=0 && 
vector.y < this.height
```

**Rendered Output:**

```
noob = ['learning','new','language'];
```

or

```
vector.x >= 0 && vector.x < this.width && vector.y >= 0 && vector.y < this.height;
```

**Desired, as more readable**

```
noob = [
  'learning',
  'new',
  'language'
];
```

or

```
(identical to input)
```

Is it possible to have CoffeeScript retain newlines in the output js?

Comment: I havn't found a way to do that. but why would you? you're not dealing with the compiled JS, only with the coffee script. as far as you're concerned the JS can even be minified. no?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I'm learning, and I believe inspection of the result will help me learn more and more quickly, and continuing to inspect will make me a better CoffeeScript programmer; plus, I think it's a bit naive to just push everything in without a care for the output, I've seen some awful .css files as a result of Sass written with that mentality

Comment: you should definitely examine the output until you get the hang of it. since coffescript can produce some weird JS. but regarding indentention and line breaks that's not really the case IMO. good luck anyways

Comment: @NitsanBaleli that's exactly why I'd like the line breaks :-) my task has an array of strings that has been written out as one 1000 char line, not to mention an if statement with four conditions (I've updated my answer) - to be fair, I am being picky, and it's output is well indented / newlined, but it still would be useful I think for the cases in the question